# Can't do what I do everyday for a living without the internet. Do I have problems?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, skills

I'm a backend web developer. If there is a problem that I solved before, while I remember there was something for this, I can't solve it by myself. I need any kind of hints or references. I can solve it only with search engines or my previous works. The real problem is, it's been more than 5 years I've been working in this line of work but it's still the same.

As a precise example, I can't set up any single Spring Boot web project with MyBatis or JPA by myself. But I can by searching the internet or referencing previous projects. The fact that I need help even with this simple matter without any sign of improvement makes me depressed.

Note that I'm not talking about troubles with learning new techs. I'm talking about can't learning the everyday basics.

Do I have problems? How to improve my situation?

Comment: If you're a web developer, I wouldn't categorise the initial setup of a web project as part of the core of what you do. Every job has those boring bits that we can't be bothered committing to memory. But you probably have a way better understanding of Java than when you started. And that is the core of what you do.

Comment: you don't need to know exactly how to do something, just that it can be done, and what search term to use to find you the solutions

Comment: I grew up in the 90s and had to rely on books to do work. I still have those books. I had this huge C library book and sometimes the examples were horribly written and no way for me to look it up other than keep trying to dig into what is going on. These days, however, I have to look up everything online too. I try think it through but sometimes I just need to get it over and done with so I just look up a how-to guide and just go down the steps.

Comment: First this is not a duplicate. The linked question ask about googling in general and as a learning tool. This is asking specifically how to keep from googling the same thing over and over. OP, you should create a tutorial for yourself on how to do each of the larger task that you have to do. I personally create markdown pages for this so that I can quickly copy and past commands or grab IP addresses for what ever the project entails. What I find is that with enough use and documentation you learn it. Its the same reason why in uni the prof says you can have an index card. You learn it by makin

Answer (score 7):

I've been a front end and back end web developer for 7 years and I still look up basic stuff all the time. Seriously I looked up how to do a switch statement in javascript like a week ago.

It's perfectly fine. Your brain prioritises learning things you actually need. Why bother memorising something you can just google in 30 seconds?
If for some reason you were forced to not use the internet, you would actually start to memorise these things out of necessity. But you will never ever have to face that scenario.

I usually have to search for how to do something because the last time I did it was six months ago and I've forgotten the specific syntax or whatever.

What you *have* learnt is how to solve the more complex problems that the trainee version of you wouldn't have been able to do.

The internet is fundamental to web development. Without it you wouldn't even have this job. So lack of internet means you wouldn't be doing this anyway. Every time you have to do web development, you have internet access. So it's a non-issue.

So my advice is not to worry about it. No-one will ever expect you to recall your language's/library's entire API from memory. I'd bet the majority of programmers spend at least 50% of their coding time reading tutorials and googling common tasks.